# codeblocks shows error in a program but i can't find it

Tags: c++

```
void PRINT_LCS(int b[][], string x, int i, int j){

    if(i==0 || j==0)
        cout<<x[0];

    if(b[i][j] == 1){
        PRINT_LCS(b, x, i-1, j-1);
        cout<<x[i];
    }
    else if(b[i][j] == 2)
        PRINT_LCS(b, x, i-1, j-1);
    else
        PRINT_LCS(b, x, i, j-1);
}
```

this is my program but i don't know why the first line has an error. The error messages are given below:

```
error: declaration of 'b' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first|
error: expected ')' before ',' token|
error: expected initializer before 'x'|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the second (column) dimension of the 2D array when declaring an array in function arguments. In your case:

```
void PRINT_LCS(int b[][COLUMN], string x, int i, int j) //replace column with the no of cols in your 2D array
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an unidimensional array as `int b[]`, the compiler does not know the size of that array, but it use b as a pointer of int and is able to access to its components, being the responsibility of the programmer to be sure that access is in the bound of the array. So, this code:

```
void f(int b[]) {
    b[5] = 15;  // access to 5th element and set value 15
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
void f(int *b) {
    *(b + 5) = 15; 
}
```

If you use a bidimensional array, the rows of the array is stored consecutively in memory, so the compiler needs to know the column size to access to an arbitrary element in the array. (Is still responsibility of the programmer to be sure the access is not out of bound). Now, this code:

```
void f(int b[][COLUMN_SIZE]) {
    b[5][3] = 15;  // access to 5th row, 3rd column and set value 15
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
void f(int *b) {
    *(b + 5 * COLUMN_SIZE + 3) = 15;
}
```

But if you don't specify the column size, how the compiler know its size?
This is generalizable for multidimensional array.

Comment: The second part is not right. `void f(int b[][COLUMN_SIZE])` is equivalent to `void f(int (*b)[COLUMN_SIZE]) { b[5][3] = 15; }`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thanks. Fixed it now, including the missing name of the function.

Comment: The function prototype is fixed but the assignment is still wrong; you have `b[5*COLUMN_SIZE+3]` where it should be `b[5][3]`. The first one denotes an array and is also an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: From the memory layout perspective, yes, they are equivalent. The result is the same. `&b[5][3] == &b[5* COLUMN_SIZE+3]` for that example.

Comment: No it isn't. Try it in your compiler, output those two addresses via `%p`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes, it is. `&b[5][3] == &b[5* COLUMN_SIZE+3]`, and `&b[5][3] ==  &(*(b + 5 * COLUMNS + 3))`. I tried that before my previous comment. Indeed, in release configuration I get _exactly_ the same assembly code. Try it you in your compiler.

Comment: You didn't put that exact code in then . [Link to example showing the difference](https://ideone.com/erZD86)

Comment: BTW I am just referring to your expression `&b[5][3] == &b[5* COLUMN_SIZE+3]`  ; you've edited your post since my earlier comments

Comment: Well, I edited my post before your second comment and the re-edited again to leave the prototype as before, before your third comment. I've introduced confusion with those editions, so sorry for that. I was comparing `&b[5][3]` in the first prototype function with `&b[5 * COLUMN_SIZE + 3]` in the second prototype function. This is the sample: https://ideone.com/R193JO. Now, I know what were you meaning.

Comment: OK. It misled me that `b` is being used for various different things. Clearer to say that `&b[5][3] == &((int *)b)[5*COLUMN_SIZE+3]`